# How do I setup a runit service in Centos which is initially stopped

Tags: linux, centos

I have a service called 'hello' which I would like to run on `CentOS release 5.8 (Final)`. However I would like it to be initially stopped.

The service is a runit service which looks like this

```
├── hello
│   ├── run
└── log
    └── run
```

The run file is as follows

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'Starting'
trap 'echo Finishing; exit 0' TERM SIGINT
while true; do
  echo 'hey'
  sleep 10
done
echo 'Finsihing'
```

The log/run file looks as follows

```
#!/bin/sh
exec svlogd -ttt /var/log/hello
```

To install the service I do the following

```
cp -r hello /var/service/hello
ln -s /var/service/hello /service/hello
ln -s /sbin/sv /etc/init.d/hello
```

At this point the service is installed and running. However, I want the service to be initially stopped.

What is the right way to configure an initially stopped service under runit in Centos?

Comment: Which version of CentOS?

Comment: The version is ```CentOS release 5.8 (Final)```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to place an empty file called `down` in the service directory alongside the run file.